# ReactJS/Javascript: Map function and JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql-js, map-function

[image]In the console, data is loaded with a JSON file that I am trying to render (see below).  The error message from Chrome is, `TypeError: data.map is not a function`.  I did not find good examples of the d3.extent function so I'm here seeking some help with this.  The Graph component looks like this:

```
constructor({data=[]}) {
  console.log('construc data:', data)
    const times = d3.extent(data.map(action => action.timestamp))
    const range = [50, 450]
    super({data})
    this.state = {data, times, range}
}
```

The JSON file:

```
{data: 
     action: 
        {action: [{action: "Changed", timestamp: 1499348050,…},…]}
```

Comment: The JSON snippet you included is not valid JSON.

Comment: So how do I parse it using d3.extent?

Comment: I think I need to do a nested d3.extent? If so, not use to pull that off. All the examples online so far have flat JSON/Arrays.

Comment: try `data.action.action.map(action => . . .)`

Comment: Map function not work on object. Map function assoicated with array.

Comment: @Helpinghand errors out.

Comment: @SagarGavhane got any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: can you provide exact data object?

Comment: Just added a screenshot.

Comment: If action property is an array of objects then try this.
`data.action.map(action => action.timestamp);`

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: Could you try `data.action.map`?

Comment: no still getting: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: Still getting: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

**Incorrect JSON**

Your JSON file is not valid as your keys need to be enclosed in quotes. Use the [JSON Validator](https://jsonlint.com/) to ensure you have a correct JSON file.

---

**Calling `.map()` on an `Object` causes a `TypeError`**

When your data is loaded from the JSON file (and does not default to an empty array as set by your constructor), ensure that it's in the shape of an `Array`, because calling the `.map()` method on an `Object` instead of an `Array` causes a `TypeError`. This is because `.map()` is part of the `Array`'s prototype and [`d3.extent(array)`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#extent) needs an `Array` as an argument.

> Read more about JavaScript's [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
>
> Read more about JavaScript's [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

---

**Correct Approach**

If your JSON is loaded in correctly into the `data` object, the following should work:

```
d3.extent(data.action.action.map(action => action.timestamp))
```